# the onload is not working on my react page

Tags: reactjs, onload

I want to run a function when the page loads, but onLoad is not working. When I try componentDidMount its says 'Cannot read property 'email' of null'. When I call the function by button press, it works. What can I do?

```js
import React from 'react'

import fire from './firebase'
import {Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import './home.css'



class Home extends React.Component{
        state = {
            email: '',
            name: ''
        }


    logout(){
        fire.auth().signOut();
    }
    whenItStarts = () => {
        var email = fire.auth().currentUser.email
        var name = fire.auth().currentUser.displayName
        this.setState({email: email})
        this.setState({name: name})
    }
    getCurrentUser = () => {
        var email = fire.auth().currentUser.email
        var name = fire.auth().currentUser.displayName
        
        alert(email + ' '+ name)
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <div onLoad = {this.whenItStarts}>
                <div className = "header">
                    <Switch>

                        <ul className = "menuList">
                            <Link to = "/profile"><li>My Profile</li></Link>
                            <li><button onClick = {this.logout}>Sign Out</button></li>
                            <li><button onClick = {this.currentUser}>Get Current User</button></li>
                             <h1>Hello there, {this.state.name}</h1>
                        </ul>
                    </Switch>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

you havn't use `componentDidMount` life cycle hook  in your code.
`componentDidMount` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted.
you don't need to use `onLoad` when you have this hook.
you can learn more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
I rewrited your code with this hook:

```
import React from "react";

import fire from "./firebase";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./home.css";

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    name: "",
  };

  logout() {
    fire.auth().signOut();
  }
  componentDidMount (){
    var email = fire.auth().currentUser.email;
    var name = fire.auth().currentUser.displayName;
    this.setState({ email: email });
    this.setState({ name: name });
  };
  getCurrentUser = () => {
    var email = fire.auth().currentUser.email;
    var name = fire.auth().currentUser.displayName;

    alert(email + " " + name);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div className="header">
            <Switch>
              <ul className="menuList">
                <Link to="/profile">
                  <li>My Profile</li>
                </Link>
                <li>
                  <button onClick={this.logout}>Sign Out</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button onClick={this.currentUser}>Get Current User</button>
                </li>
                <h1>Hello there, {this.state.name}</h1>
              </ul>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

please let me know if you still have any problem

Comment: oh ok. Thank you! Have a nice day